# My hosting company does not support SUPER privilege - can I use CiviCRM with them?

Tags: joomla, installation, mysql

I finally after a week and 3 tickets got CiviCRM/Joomla to install on my Startlogic hosted server, but I can't add anything to the database.  The final response I got from Startlogic support was "Hello Michael, We apologize for any inconvenience this has caused you. It looks like the extension which you are trying to install requires super privilege which is not supported. Also, we do not support binary logging which the extension requires. Thus, you are receiving the error message. You can try using any alternative extension and check."  At this point I think they are blowing me off and about to go through the headache of switching hosts.
Is there anything I can do get CiviCRM to work on the Startlogic server, as they seem not to want to help.

Comment: As far as I can remember, not allowing root/superuser/admin access on a hosting account is fairly common practice if you use a "plain" hosting account. I haven't used one for ages, because of this problem, using instead service providers that offer a virtual server (more work to get running, but you are not limited by the account type).

That said, I believe there are providers offering "root access" - you just need to examine what's being offered. It's not blowing you off (rather trying to provide a secure service for all) unless they guaranteed something else originally.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: *"Is there anything I can do get CiviCRM to work on the Startlogic server, as they seem not to want to help."* - for your/your org's sanity, host with an organisation that supports the tools you use fully.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two scenarios in which CiviCRM requires the SUPER privilege:

- You're using a very old version of MySQL.  Versions of MySQL [5.1.6 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815837/in-mysql-what-privileges-are-required-for-executing-a-trigger) support the TRIGGER permission.  Before that, SUPER was necessary.  MySQL 5.1 reached its "end of life" at the end of 2013.  No modern server should have it installed.
- You're attempting to use the advanced logging feature: **Administer menu » System Settings » Misc**, *Logging* set to **Yes**.  If you need this feature, you really need a VPS.

All that said - @Christia is right.  StartLogic is entry-level hosting.  CiviCRM has heftier requirements than entry-level hosting gives you.  Expect poor performance unless you move hosts.

Answer (score 3):

You will either need to get a hosting plan that allows root access and "binary logging" or pay your host to install it. I recommend the former. In my experience, managed types of hosting don't tend to be easy or possible to use CiviCRM and offer a limited list of software or extensions already preloaded. There are hosting companies out there that are familiar with civicrm that can give you more control.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need Super Privilege for the two scenarios Jon G outlined - you should be able to use a shared host without an issue. Its unlikely a shared host would give you Super Privilege anyways. If you are on a budget and need a shared host, may I suggest one of the following:

- CiviHosting - Specializes in CiviCRM hosting. ([Founding CiviCRM Supporting Partner](https://civicrm.org/providers/CiviHosting))
- TMDHosting - Shared host with CiviCRM expertise. ([CiviCRM Supporting Partner](https://civicrm.org/providers/Tmd-Hosting))
- [Stablehost](https://www.stablehost.com/) - They have no expertise with CiviCRM - but I have used them with no problems and they are budget (look for discount codes).
- Electric Embers - Affordable hosting - but no cpanel - I recommend only if you have the expertise. ([CiviCRM Supporting Partner](https://civicrm.org/providers/Electric-Embers))

Good Luck with your project.

PS: Avoid any and all hosts owned by EIG (such as startlogic)